# what are the jar files needed to display a jasperreport with a bar chart , in a netbeans ide 8.0

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

I'm using netbeans 8.0 ide with jdk 8. And I want to view a report using jasper which includes a bar chart. But it gets error like this:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/chart/plot/PlotOrientation
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.charts.type.PlotOrientationEnum.(PlotOrientationEnum.java:42)

What are the jar files needed to display a jasperreport with a bar chart , in a netbeans ide 8.0. Anyone please help me.

Comment: Switch to **maven**; this build management handles transitive jar dependencies for you. You add a dependency to jasperreport with latest version number, easily to be found, and a local maven repository of all needed jars is made, reusable by other projects. Just has an other convention for src folders: src/main/java, src/main/resources, src/test/java (unit tests). Ideal if you want to upgrade in the future. _Start with a new maven project._

Answer (score 5):

You can use jasperreports-0.6.3.jar and itextpdf-5.1.0.jar in the library folder clean the project and again run.